# How can I reverse the order of a EmbeddedDocument QuerySet using MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Below are simplified versions of my classes. All I want to do is reverse the order of the embedded documents so the newest is shown first, not last.

```
class User(Document):
        username = StringField(unique=True) 
        userreviews = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Review)


class Review(EmbeddedDocument):
    review_date = DateTimeField()
```

I am first getting the user like so:

```
the_user: QuerySet = user.User.objects.filter(
    username=request.form["username"])
```

Then I get the first user and get the first 10 reviews of that user using slice (for pagination reasons):

```
review_query: QuerySet = the_user.fields(
        slice__userreviews=[0, 10]).first()
```

How can I reverse the order of the reviews before I get the reviews via slice? Do I really have to store them reversed to accomplish this or is there a way to accomplish this after they are stored?

Comment: I had similar problem of ordering embedded list while I was using mongoengine, sometime ago. I came to conclusion, it was not possible. I ended up creating another Document to store this data, just  for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty surprised at the difficulty I'm facing trying to do something so (seemingly) simple. Embedded documents are great in theory but working with and sorting them is becoming extremely frustrating.

Comment: FYI it seems like you can do a lot more by adding an EmbeddedDocumentField to a SortedListField instead of using EmbeddedDocumentListField. EmbeddedDocumentListField is very limited by comparison it seems.

Comment: I had some problem with using this too .I think it is not possible to do special ordering (like ordering with multiple fields). My use case was not exactly like yours, but related to ordering, though I don't actually remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this myself in case someone runs into the same issue. It seems ordering on the `EmbeddedDocumentListField` is a bit limited. It was much easier to change the fields in my class from this:

```
class User(Document):
    username = StringField(unique=True) 
    userreviews = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Review)
```

to this:

```
class User(Document):
    username = StringField(unique=True)
    userreviews = SortedListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Review),
                              ordering="review_date", reverse=True)
```

From there I could also switch over to array-slicing syntax to paginate the query:

```
all_reviews = first_user.userreviews[0:10]
```